# Not able to remove element from list

Tags: java

I am developing an application that updates the quantity of items in a cart. Below is the code snippet that traverses through the input list of items and updates the quantity of the item.

```
       for (int i = 0; i < InputOrder.size(); i++) {

            ProdRefCode = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode();
            ProdModelNo = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode();
            ProdCost = InputOrder.get(i).getProdCost();
            updatedQuantity =Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("ddlQuantity" + i));
            UpdatedQuantity.add(updatedQuantity);
            Cart updateCart = new Cart(ProdRefCode, ProdModelNo, ProdCost, UpdatedQuantity);
            OutputOrder.add(updateCart);
            UpdatedQuantity.clear();
            updateCart = null;
            listCount = OutputOrder.size();
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that my `UpdatedQuantity` is holding multiple values. I tried to clear the `UpdatedQuantity` list, but that would in turn make `UpdatedQuantity = 0` in my updateCart. I also tried using `UpdatedQuantity.Remove(i)` but that is also removing the element.

Also I just want only one value in all my lists.

Could anyone help me out with this?
Any suggestion /help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: Cart Code

```
public class Cart {

    private List<String> _prodRefCode;
    private List<String>_prodModel;
    private List<Integer>_prodCost;
    private List<Integer>_prodQuantity;

    public Cart() {}

    public Cart(List<String> _prodRefCode, List<String> _prodModel, List<Integer> _prodCost, List<Integer> _prodQuantity) {
        this._prodRefCode = _prodRefCode;
        this._prodModel = _prodModel;
        this._prodCost = _prodCost;
        this._prodQuantity = _prodQuantity;
    }

    public List<String> getProdRefCode() {
        return _prodRefCode;
    }

    public void setProdRefCode(List<String> _prodRefCode) {
        this._prodRefCode = _prodRefCode;
    }

    public List<String> getProdModel() {
        return _prodModel;
    }

    public void setProdModel(List<String> _prodModel) {
        this._prodModel = _prodModel;
    }

    public List<Integer> getProdCost() {
        return _prodCost;
    }

    public void setProdCost(List<Integer> _prodCost) {
        this._prodCost = _prodCost;
    }

    public List<Integer> getProdQuantity() {
        return _prodQuantity;
    }

    public void setProdQuantity(List<Integer> _prodQuantity) {
        this._prodQuantity = _prodQuantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the class of "UpdatedQuantity" with the capital "U"?

Comment: @YazadKhambata It looks like a `List<Integer>`

Comment: Well then it shouldn't be "UpdatedQuantity =0" in the prose below the code snippet.

Comment: @YazadKhambata I think he meant `updatedQuantity`, as assigning `0` to an object is not possible. That's the problem when you have two variables with the same name, only different by the first chars case...

Comment: But I agree, adding the variables types to the code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: what are you exactly trying to hold in the List? only item quantities or both items and their quantities as well?

Comment: .. I am sorry for the naming conventions ..what actually i am trying to do is trying to update the value of my item quantity .. what will happen is that updatedQuantity will hold the value that has been modified from the front end and that value will be stored in the list .. the problem is that i am pulling the entire list from UI and transfering it to a new list after updating the value ...my List<Integer> UpdatedQuantity holds multiple values as it iterates ..all i want is that this list should only hold that value that is assigned by updatedQuantity ..

I hopei have cleared my problem

Comment: Why do you have a list if you want this list to have only one element? you should give more context around your code, and also the type of each variable you use in this loop.

Comment: because UpdatedQuantity is List <Integer> type and only for updating I want it to hold 1 item . 
This list id passed in a session that will display all the values ..

I hope this helps

Comment: Can you show the `Cart` class code?

Comment: @AbbéRésina this is my Cart Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only one element in the list you are passing as a parameter to the `Cart` constructor, you can just create a new one in each iteration and not use the global list called `UpdatedQuantity`, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < InputOrder.size(); i++) {
    ProdRefCode = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode();
    ProdModelNo = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode(); // same as above ?
    ProdCost = InputOrder.get(i).getProdCost();
    updatedQuantity =Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("ddlQuantity" + i));

    // Create a list that holds one quantity value
    List<Integer> quantity = Arrays.asList(updatedQuantity);
    Cart updateCart = new Cart(ProdRefCode, ProdModelNo, ProdCost, quantity);
    OutputOrder.add(updateCart);

    listCount = OutputOrder.size(); // ?
}
```

What you have tried so far, clearing the list in the iteration is not good because each `Cart` object holds a reference (I assume `Cart` is not copying the list, since we don't have this code, I can't tell exactly) on the `UpdatedQuantity` list. It means that at the end, all `Cart` instances in `OutputOrder` will share the same list, that shall be empty (if cleared at each iteration, or with all updates, if not clearing).

Comment: yup..!! this works just the way i wanted it to .. :) thanks a lot ..!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you clearly understand the concept of passing by reference or value system.

```
for (int i = 0; i < InputOrder.size(); i++) {
        ProdRefCode = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode();
        ProdModelNo = InputOrder.get(i).getProdRefCode();
        ProdCost = InputOrder.get(i).getProdCost();
        updatedQuantity =Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("ddlQuantity" + i));
        UpdatedQuantity.add(updatedQuantity);
        listCount = OutputOrder.size();
}
Cart updateCart = new Cart(ProdRefCode, ProdModelNo, ProdCost, UpdatedQuantity);
OutputOrder.add(updateCart);
```

This should fix the multiple value problem. Let me know if this helps.

**Explanation**: Think about my code this way. The `UpdatedQuantity` points to a object on which you are pushing a new value each time in the for loop. Hence, when you are creating a cart (in your code: passing the `UpdatedQuantity` pointer) your `cart.UpdatedQuantity` points to the updated object (new push). In my code, you are creating the cart outside of the loop, by the time your `UpdatedQuantity` is updated with all the values required.

Comment: i am sorry but i really cant see the difference , i guess i have done the same thing the point is that while iterating it holds multiple values .

Comment: yeah i saw but this is also not helping..:) i guess i will change my approach .. ill drop the List and will just go with int .. as suggested by @Abbé Résina ..  thanks eveyone for your help .. :)